# Unix (MacOS) Command Line tool for manipulating HSV of Videos and/or Images

Tags: video, image-processing, macos, unix

I have a directory full of about 10,000 videos, and I need to manipulate their color scheme in a few ways. I would like to make a copy where they are all slightly bluer/darker, and another copy where they are all slightly redder/lighter.

I did similar manipulation to the audio using `ffmpeg`, and wrote a script to process all 10,000 videos.

I'd like to write a script to do this visual manipulation as well. Any ideas of what I can use?

Note: Ideally, I'd like something that can handle videos, but if it can only edit images, I can probably find some way to map the manipulation onto each frame of the video and reconstruct the video after-the-fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, `ffmpeg` can handle this too! In particular, I found this page: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq.

Using the `eq` filter, one can modify contract, brightness, saturation, gamma, r, g, b, and more.